# Nginx configuration 502 bad gateway error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I have a configured nginx sites enabled/available that when I run:

```
nginx -t
```

I get a successful test and when I:

```
service nginx restart
thin restart -s 1
```

My 502 error goes away but only for ten seconds and then it shows up again.  my sites-available is:

```
upstream myapp {
server 0.0.0.0:3000;
```

}

server {
    listen   80 default;

```
access_log /webservices/crawler/log/access.log;
error_log /webservices/crawler/error.log;

root   /webservices/crawler/public/;
index  index.html;

client_max_body_size 500M;

location / {
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    if (-f $request_filename/index.html) {
        rewrite (.*) $1/index.html;
        break;
    }

    if (-f $request_filename.html) {
        rewrite (.*) $1.html;
        break;
    }

    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        proxy_pass http://myapp;
        break;
    }
}
```

}

Does anyone know why my config only works for a few seconds? Thank you for any help and just let me know if you need to see any of my other code.

thin restart -s 2 output:

```
    /# thin restart -s 2
Stopping server on 0.0.0.0:3000 ... 
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/daemonizing.rb:131:in `send_signal': Can't stop process, no PID found in tmp/pids/thin.3000.pid (Thin::PidFileNotFound)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/daemonizing.rb:113:in `kill'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:93:in `block in stop'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:134:in `tail_log'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:92:in `stop'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:187:in `run_command'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:152:in `run!'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.5.1/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/thin:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
Stopping server on 0.0.0.0:3001 ... 
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/daemonizing.rb:131:in `send_signal': Can't stop process, no PID found in tmp/pids/thin.3001.pid (Thin::PidFileNotFound)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/daemonizing.rb:113:in `kill'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:93:in `block in stop'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:134:in `tail_log'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:92:in `stop'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:187:in `run_command'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:152:in `run!'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.5.1/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/thin:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
Starting server on 0.0.0.0:3000 ... 
Starting server on 0.0.0.0:3001 ...
```

I am pretty sure this is a Thin issue and not an nginx issue so I am posting an update.  Sorry for any confusion.

my website is up for about 10 seconds and then I get the 502 nginx error. My nginx config seems fine and the nginx -t is successful. My error message is this:

thin restart -s 5

/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/daemonizing.rb:131:in `send_signal': Can't stop process, no PID found in tmp/pids/thin.3004.pid (Thin::PidFileNotFound)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/daemonizing.rb:113:in`kill'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:93:in `block in stop'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:134:in`tail_log'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:92:in `stop'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:187:in`run_command'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:152:in `run!'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.5.1/bin/thin:6:in`'
    from /usr/local/bin/thin:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/thin:23:in`'

I have checked the PID,s and they are there.  Does anyone have any idea on what is going on here?  thank you and I appreciate any advice.

Comment: this is my actual output of nginx -t:

nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

Comment: 502 means you app server went down (crached) or doesn't accept connections.

Comment: Is thin running when you get the error? I see this error when thin has been closed either due to insufficient memory or by a monitoring process. (You might be better off asking on serverfault too)

Comment: Yes I am pretty sure thin is running, I will post my thin restart -s 2 output above for you.

Comment: A bit of offtopic, but using `if` in nginx config is usually a bad idea. Read http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Check_IF_File_Exists. Here what it might looks like https://gist.github.com/alexeyten/ca3af91fa06e1536df26

Comment: Interesting so you are saying I should try replacing those if's with try_files?

Comment: Still no luck=( I don't understand why my nginx -t says everything is fine when its obviously notXD thanks for the suggestions though!

Comment: I am pretty sure this is a thin issue and not an nginx problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found what I needed to run to clean up those thin errors.  I don't know why but running:

```
bundle exec thin start -p 3000
```

fixed my situation.  Thanks for everyone's help! I could not have found it without you.

Comment: This actually only starts a local server on my machine=( so as soon as I get offline its down. yikes! not the answer but maybe close!=D

Comment: I think that somehow I lost my thin config file.  It is no where to be found, does anyone know how to generate the config.yml that is needed for thin?  Thank you anyone who knows anything.