# missing thin.yml config file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, thin

I am trying to fix a server that is useing nginx and thin.  My original question is here:

[Nginx configuration 502 bad gateway error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417097/nginx-configuration-502-bad-gateway-error?noredirect=1#comment35885808_23417097)

I am re posting because after a lot of research, it seems like I am missing my config.yml for thin and it is not an nginx problem even though I get the 502 error page on my site.  All posts I have seen has shown that it should be located in etc/thin dir however there is no such dir on my ssh.

Does anyone know how to generate this config.yml or know where else it could be?  Thank you for any advice and information.